# Flask-login remember does not work

Tags: python, cookies, flask, flask-login, flask-oauthlib

I am developing a small web application. I am using https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-OAuth library for Social Authentication from Google. Also, `Flask-Login`. I have successfully set up the authorization callback and authorized the user. I am able to successfully login the user as well using `login_user(user, remember=True)`.

This creates a cookie named `remember_token` with expiration of 365 days. However, the problem occurs when I close the browser(Firefox, Chrome) and when I reopen my application.

Using `Tools->Privacy->Remove Individual Cookies` in Firefox, I can see the remember_token cookie. However, when I navigate to the index page `/` , I have set up this function ..

```
@main.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        print_debug('User is authenticated in /')
        return redirect(url_for('.home'))
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

@main.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    do_something()
```

Navingating to `/` prints the debug information and a successful redirect to `/home` occurs. However, this redirect is intercepted by `@login_required` and I am redirected to `/google-login?next=%2Fhome` asking me to login again. Also, the `remember_token` is also deleted at this stage. I confirm it after checking it in Firefox.

I can't understand why the remember function is not working properly. Or Why the `remember_token` is being deleted. I don't do anything in between. Step wise,

- I initially login. Till the browser is not closed, everything works fine. All `@login_required`s work.
- When I close the browser and reopen, till I don't open my webapp on
  `localhost:5000` there remains a cookie names `remember_token`.
- As soon as I open, the first `current_user.is_authenticated` on `/` returns
  True and from this point onward, every @login_required asks for
  re-login.

I am using Flask-sqlalchemy and MySQL for database. My user model is

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    username = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True, index=True)
```

My User Loader

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    print_debug("User loader called with id %s" % user_id)
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of `flask-login` are you using and could you show your user loader function?

Comment: So you have two ways of logging in: database and OAuth? If yes does the behavior differ for the two login methods?

Comment: No. I only use Oauth. As of now, I am not using the password_hash field of the Table. I just included it for implementing my own login in future.